# Multiple database Django

Tags: django

tengo una aplicación que usa actualmente una sola Base de Datos, bien ahora la cuestion surgue cuando me piden que haga multiempresa, para lo cual se me habria ocurrido usar la opción de multiples BD propia de Django.

Bien ahora el cliente accede al **LOGIN** donde selecciona una **EMPRESA** y accede con su usuario y clave, al entrar deberá ver los datos solo de la **EMPRESA** seleccionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es como puedo identificar o como establecer que al iniciar sesión defina X o Y Base de Datos según la **Empresa** seleccionada.

Estaba leyendo la documentación pero no me comenta como definir una u otra para estos casos [multiples DB Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/)

Gracias de Antemano por cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Pues no es tan difícil, lo que de pronto necesitas es guardar en una base de datos global o centralizada (o en un archivo sin más) un registro donde diga que de acuerdo a una empresa debe usar una bd u otra, y lo que tienes que hacer, es que en el login, en la sesión verificar la empresa, y configurar toda tu app para que haga las peticiones a esa bd. Puedes hacerlo bien creando un nuevo campo en la sesión, un nuevo modelo (fijate como ponen el user en el request) o si quieres guardarlo en una cookie para cada petición que te haga ese mismo cliente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día:

Tengo un proyecto, pero no son con múltiples base de datos, si no `Multi-Tenant`(multi-inquilinos).

¿Qué son las aplicaciones de múltiples inquilinos?

Las aplicaciones para múltiples inquilinos le permiten atender a múltiples clientes con una instalación de la aplicación. Cada cliente tiene sus datos completamente aislados en tal arquitectura. Cada cliente se llama un inquilino.
La mayoría de las aplicaciones modernas de Software como Servicio son multi arrendatario. Ya sea Salesforce, Freshbooks, Zoho o Wordpress, la mayoría de las aplicaciones modernas basadas en la nube, se entregan con una arquitectura multi-tenant.

ejemplo:

> inquilino.dominio.com

```
from django.db import models
from tenant_schemas.models import TenantMixin

class Client(TenantMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    paid_until =  models.DateField()
    on_trial = models.BooleanField()
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    # default true, schema will be automatically created and synced when it is saved
    auto_create_schema = True
```

Primero tenemos nuestro 'public', viene hacer como nuestro dominio.

```
from customers.models import Client

# create your public tenant
tenant = Client(domain_url='my-domain.com', # don't add your port or www here! on a local server you'll want to use localhost here
                schema_name='public',
                name='Schemas Inc.',
                paid_until='2016-12-05',
                on_trial=False)
tenant.save()
```

Ahora podemos crear nuestro primer inquilino real.

```
from customers.models import Client

# create your first real tenant
tenant = Client(domain_url='tenant.my-domain.com', # No agregue su puerto o www aquí!
                schema_name='tenant1',
                name='Fonzy Tenant',
                paid_until='2014-12-05',
                on_trial=True)
tenant.save() # migrate_schemas Llamado automáticamente, su inquilino está listo para ser utilizado!
```

Con esto he podido informame más sobre los inquilinos y la muestra rápida que no proporciona `django-tenant-schemas`, para tener más información leer la [documentación](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: saludos gracias por tu respuesta según noto usa PostgreSQL para usar dicho metodo esta interesante sin dudar pero en este instante uso MySQL

Comment: Lee esto amigo https://github.com/mik3y/django-db-multitenant